# Как показать окно пользователю который зашел первый раз?

Tags: всплывающее-окно, javascript

Всем доброе время суток. Хотелось бы показать пользователю который зашел на сайт первый раз окно, а потом уже его не показывать. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно реализовать подобное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ставьте куки. Если куки нет - показывайте окно.

[Тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) и [тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie) все развернуто.